# RDS snapshot to mysqldump

Tags: backup, amazon-web-services, snapshot, rds

We have accidentally deleted some of the data entries from the RDS db and came to know after 10 days, so to recover data from rds snapshots,we  figured out these possible solutions

- Restore the db to 10 days back restore point -> then match it with current mysqldump and add the entries for these 10 days manually, which doesn't sound me a great idea.
- Launch the new db instance (not restore but a separate) from the snapshot -> mysqldump the data -> fetch the entries -> Add to new db, Don't know if it is possible to launch a new RDS instance from automatic snapshot.
- To convert the automatic snapshot to manual one , i  have copied it to another region. So if i restore rds from this manual point then,

  will it launch a new rds instance with same db host name and shutdown the old one ?

  OR

  will it launch a new rds instance with other host name?

Please advise how i can access theses entries without interrupting the current rds instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical process is to copy the automatic snapshot then launch a separate (usually smaller single-AZ instance) from it.

It's not that much of a hassle and it avoids impacting performance of your production instance during the dump too.